# NoClassDefFoundError io/atlassian/fugue/Suppliers JIRA

Tags: java, jira

I am trying to list JIRA projects with the Java SDK following https://www.baeldung.com/jira-rest-api (I could not find another example in Google for this) with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JiraRestClient jiraRestClient = getJiraRestClient(URI.create("uri"),"username","token");


    try {
        Iterable<BasicProject> projects =  jiraRestClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().get();
        projects.forEach(basicProject -> System.out.println(basicProject.getName()));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient(URI uri, String username, String password) {
    return new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
            .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, username, password);
}
```

However, it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/atlassian/fugue/Suppliers
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.<clinit>(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.doCreate(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:61)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.create(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:68)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    at JiraPlayground.getJiraRestClient(JiraPlayground.java:30)
    at JiraPlayground.main(JiraPlayground.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.atlassian.fugue.Suppliers
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.atlassian.fugue/fugue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Any idea how to run the code correctly?

Comment: How are you running such example, from your favorite IDE?? or from command line?

Comment: @CarlitosWay from intellij but i dont see that as a problem

Comment: Can you add all of the error Message, especially the end?

Comment: Is there any reason you're listing projects using REST API? ProjectService::getAllProjects can do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Atlassian</id>
            <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-atlassian-external/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527051/309683, make sure `fuge` is not marked as `provided` if you are running the app outside Jira (e.g. not a plugin/extension).

Then this code should work:

```java
package org.example;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;

import java.net.URI;

public class Main {
    private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://your-jira-url.com";
    private static final String JIRA_USERNAME = "your-jira-username";
    private static final String JIRA_PASSWORD = "your-jira-password";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URI jiraServerUri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        try (JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD)) {
            Iterable<BasicProject> projects = client.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
            for (BasicProject project : projects) {
                System.out.println(project.getKey() + ": " + project.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot, but I'll suggest to change the scope of the library *fugue* from `provided` to `compile` and try again ...

Comment: Strange enough for me the error goes away with this change, but when I add the project in another one, it does not work anymore.

Comment: What happen? Under the deployment that you describe, are you getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` ??

Answer (score 1):

The `io.atlassian.fugue.Suppliers` class is part of a different artifact that is not included in the JRJC maven dependencies. This causing exception at runtime.

Try to add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
<artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
<version>4.7.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have tried this combination but still the same error

Comment: @Murat If you copy (and just slightly modify) the solution from another place, even copying the misspelled word "depencies", I would consider as polite gesture to add the link: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/I-am-getting-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-io-atlassian-fugue/qaq-p/1096913 to give the credit to the original author.

Comment: By mentioning the typo, which you copied, I wanted to remind you that you copied work of someone else without mentioning here original source. Correcting the typo is not the edit I was asking you for.